# cURL works but mechanize doesn't

Tags: ruby, curl, mechanize, www-mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am trying to scrape my university web site using ruby mechanize. This my ruby script;

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('https://kampus.izu.edu.tr')
```

This script doesn't return response. I need to see login page but the response is different. I also tried it with cURL like this;

```
curl https://kampus.izu.edu.tr
```

This works and return the login page. What am I missing?

Comment: This works for me on mechanize (2.7.5) / ruby 2.4.2p198

Comment: @pguardiario i have same environment. can you add the response and ruby script ?

Comment: I just typed those 3 lines into irb and I got a good response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are storing the output of agent.get(). From your example, I don't see how you would be using/printing the response of this request.

Try this:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new 
page = agent.get("https://kampus.izu.edu.tr")
puts page.body
```

The .get() method returns a Mechanize::Page object that you can call other methods on, such as .css(), to select elements by css selectors. Check out the documentation [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize)